# nginx proxy_pass do not pass uri

Tags: nginx, webserver, proxypass, ssi

My goal is, that the call of `domain.com/do/that/` will include the page `otherdomain.com/for/that/`and replaces a part of that content with ssi & subs filter.
Also, it is important if someone calls `domain.com/do/that/for-me`, the included page will just request `otherdomain.com/for/that` and **not** `otherdomain.com/for/that/for-me`.

I currently have set up this:

```
location ^~/do/that/ {
  proxy_pass http://otherdomain.com/do/that/;

  ssi on;
  subs_filter_types text/html;

  set $includeUri "";
  if ( $uri != "/do/that/" ){
    set $includeUri "$uri-parts";
  }

 subs_filter '<div class="rpl-container">' '<div class="rpl-container"><!--# include virtual="/my-ssi-include/$includeUri" -->' ir;
}
```

What would be the way to achieve that "ignore" of uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found out the solution:

I just use a var with the static URL and set it to the proxy_pass

```
location ^~/do/that/ {
  set $staticUrl 'http://otherdomain.com/do/that/';
  proxy_pass $staticUrl;

  ssi on;
  subs_filter_types text/html;

  if ($uri ~* "/do/that/(.*\.html)"){
    set $includeUri "$1";
  }

 subs_filter '<div class="rpl-container">' '<div class="rpl-container"><!--# include virtual="/my-ssi-include/$includeUri" -->' ir;
}
```